# How to handle 2-way model view updating in AngularJS + Socket.IO

Tags: sockets, angularjs

So I have this piece of code, that handles the updating of a model

```
  // Edit todo.
  $scope.editTodo = function(todo) {
    var newTitle = prompt('Edit todo', todo.title);
    if (newTitle) {
      todo.title = newTitle;
      todo.$update();

      socket.emit('update_todo', todo);
    }
  }
```

Where the 'todo' parameter is send from the view.

I then have this piece of code, that listens for the 'update_todo' event, and updates the model view on the other active sockets/clients.

```
  socket.on('todoUpdated', function(data) {
    for (var i in $scope.todos) {
      if ($scope.todos[i]._id == data._id) {
        $scope.todos[i] = data;
      }
    }  
  });
```

However, say I have just edited a model in "client1" switch to "client2", and try to edit the same model, I get the following error:

```
  TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '$update'
```

What to do? And, is there a smarter/better way of updating the model view instead of doing the for loop? Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: How are you calling the `editTodo` method? Could you provide a Plunker/jsFiddle script with your code?

Comment: This is pretty much how my code look: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/307/

Comment: @MichaelBenford got any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
  socket.on('todoUpdated', function(data) {
    var newStatus = data.completed;

    for (var i in $scope.todos) {
      if ($scope.todos[i]._id == data._id) {
        $scope.todos[i].completed = newStatus;
      }
    }
  });
```

Anyone have a better way of doing this, please tell :)

Comment: I guess your solution is correct. Before, you were replacing the Todo object created by Angular with the one sent by SocketIO, which had no method `$update`. As a side note, you could try to make the todo list a hash table so you wouldn't need to iterate on it in order to find a specific todo.

Comment: Could you point me in a direction? Not sure what you mean by hash table?

Comment: What I meant was that you could try changing your code so you can get a todo by doing `$scope.todos[data._id]` instead of iterating on a list. It's a small optimization; perhaps it isn't worth the trouble of changing your code.

Comment: But Angular's filtering and sortBy won't work unless the object is an array.